# Designing stored procedure to work with Multiple Tables which have different formats and logic

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, database-design

T-SQL, SQL Server Management Studio 15.0.18131.0

We have a set of tables which we need to validate. These all have similar columns - not exactly the same, but when reading them in, we can infer the same information. However, each of these tables have slightly more or less columns that will use different logic to validate. For example:

- Table **A** = [ColA, ColB, ColC]
- Table **B** = [ColA, ColY, ColC]
- Validate for table A Uses column A and C, but also considers B important.
- Validate for table B uses column A and C only.

As I see it with my limited SQL experience, I have a few options:

1. Create a stored procedure for each table to validate on
2. In one stored procedure, create a validate query for each table and each validation logic type
3. In one stored procedure, split the validate queries into pieces of strings (for dynamic SQL) and piece together each validate query based on what logic each table needs.

Currently, we're doing something like #3.

```
DECLARE @PartA ....
DECLARE @PartB ....

DECLARE @Validate = @PartA + @PartB

EXEC @Validate
```

This is mainly done to let us print the query that will be executed when we pass in a debug flag, instead of executing the query.

But in my current scenario, there are 5 tables with 6 validations, and there are two different logic scenarios (two tables are a little different from the other 3). This becomes a little crazy, as now we have 5 source table variables, 5 destination table variables, 11 statement variables, and a bunch of other small ones.

Queries end up becoming like this:

```
SET @ValidateQuery1 = @Validate1 + @Validate2 + @Validate4 + @Validate5 + ' COUNT(PlanningCategoryKey) KeyCount FROM (' +  @Validate3   + @Validate5 + @Validate6 + @Table1 + @Validate7 + ')A' + @Validate8 + @Validate9
```

Now, I'm not too experienced with SQL, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to accomplish this.

I have two questions:

1. Is there a built-in or efficient way to print out the query instead of executing it? SSMS has a 'Include query with result' option, but that also executes the query. I haven't found any specific results that show me how to do this without me putting my queries as a string and then printing them like we do now.
2. Is there any design principle, guideline or general consensus designing for such a scenario? We're working to standardize the the source tables to make it easier to perform validations, but these come from external data sources, so we don't have direct control.

Thank you for your time and answers.

Comment: It might make more sense to create several SPs with each one performing a particular kind of validation, e.g email addresses, order history, past due balances, ... . Then run all of the applicable SPs against the appropriate tables. It isn't clear whether the validations are performed against all of the tables at the same time or a single table is validated when needed. You could use [`session_context`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-set-session-context-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to pass a debug flag in and the resulting SQL out.

Comment: Instead of declaring many variables like PartA, PartB, you could perhaps create and use a table variable (or temporary table) instead. You could insert one row into the table variable for each of your tables.

Comment: @HABO Thanks for the idea. So basically the data validations are run all at once. As in, every night, we check all the source tables (count 5) and validate them all in one go. The idea is we have a taxonomy that we want to maintain, given that the data isn't in our control, and we're trying to set it up in a way that we know if somethings off once the validations are run.

Comment: @MoeSisko Thanks, I'll look into table variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one validation per table.  The data and rules are clearly not the same so why would you treat them as such?  If you have similar sub-validations you can write a function same as a procedural language and factor that into your query/procedure.

Doing this also means there is less reason to print the query because unlike dynamic SQL you know what it is going to be!

Another approach would be to push all your source tables into a standard table and apply validations on that.  Without knowing the data and situation though it's hard to know if that would be better or worse.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Perhaps I could have been clearer in my post. The data are the same, the columns are slightly different (more or less columns that we ignore, or differently named columns). But yes, the logic is slightly different depending on the tables. 

For example, for Table A, We might add a "WHERE ColB IN ('x', 'y')", while for Table B, we won't add that WHERE clause because we don't care about that column for Table B.

Hope that clarifies my question. Does your answer change given this info?

Comment: Not really.  I'd start with doing each one separately.  As you progress you might find some refactoring opportunities.